# Given a Bayes Network, calculate $p(a | b, \neg c)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian, bayesian-network

I am assigned a homework but I cannot figure out how to solve it.

Given this Bayes' Network:

[image: Network]

calculate $p(a | b, \neg c)$.

This is what I have done up to now:

\begin{align}  
p(a | b, \neg c) & \propto p(a,b,\neg c) \\  
& = \sum_{d} p(a,b,\neg c, d) \\
& = \sum_d p(a)p(b|a)p(\neg c | a) p(d|a) \\
& = p(a)p(b|a)p(\neg c | a)\sum_d p(d|a)
\end{align}

Now, I can see from the picture that $p(a) = \frac{1}{2}$, but what about the other terms such as $p(b|a)$, $p(\neg c | a)$ and $p(d|a)$?

Comment: $P(b|a)$ is already specified in the above diagram - given that $a$ occurs, the probability that $b$ occurs is $\frac{4}{5}$. Same for the others.

Comment: You don't need $p(d | a)$.  It only occurs in the sum $\sum_d p(d | a)$ which must be $1$ because you are summing a pdf over all values

Comment: @0XLR What about the other terms?

Comment: The comment above mine answers that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

\begin{align}  
p(a | b, \neg c) & \propto p(a,b,\neg c) \\  
& = \sum_{d} p(a,b,\neg c, d) \\
& = \sum_d p(a)p(b|a)p(\neg c | a) p(d|a) \\
& = p(a)p(b|a)p(\neg c | a)\sum_d p(d|a) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{4}{5} \times (1 - p(c | a)) \\
& = \frac{4}{10} \times (1 - \frac{1}{3}) \\
& = \frac{4}{10} \times \frac{2}{3}  \\
& = \frac{4}{15}
\end{align}

Since $p(a)$, $p(b|a)$ and $p(\neg c | a) = 1 - p(c | a)$ can be read in the Bayesian Network and $\sum_d p(d|a) = 1$ of course.

Comment: **Note:**  You have calculated $p(a, b, \neg c)$ which is *proportional to* $p(a\mid b,\neg c)$, and **not** equal to it. $$p(a\mid b,\neg c)=\dfrac{p(a, b, \neg c)}{p(a, b,\neg c)+p(\neg a,b,\neg c)}$$